# Why is my product image causing an error on WooCommerce checkout?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have this code which returns the status of an order, I would like to also like to return the product image (or images if multiple products have been purchased) in the same way (i.e `echo` 'product image').

**The code:**

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_thankyou', 'custom_content_thankyou', 10, 1 );

function custom_content_thankyou($order_id) {
    if ( ! $order_id )
        return;

    // Get an instance of the WC_Order object
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    // Get the order key
    $order_key = $order->get_order_key();

    // Get the order number
    $order_key = $order->get_order_number();

    if($order->is_paid())
        $paid = __('yes');
    else
        $paid = __('no');

    // Loop through order items
    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {

        // Get the product object
        $product = $item->get_product();

        // Get the product Id
        $product_id = $product->get_id();
        
        /* Get product thumbnail */
        $thumbnail = $_product->get_image(); // THIS IS THE LINE CAUSING THE ERROR

        // Get the product name
        $product_id = $item->get_name();
    
    }

    // Output some data
    echo '<p>Order ID: '. $order_id . ' — Order Status: ' . $order->get_status() . ' — Order is paid: ' . $paid . '</p>';
   // echo 'product image';

}
```

**The code I have above works except for this line:**

```
$thumbnail = $_product->get_image();
```

**Which causes this error:**

*Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_image() on null in /home/customer/www/example.com/public_html/wp-content/themes/kalium-child/functions.php:208 Stack trace: #0 /home/customer/www/example.com/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(307): custom_content_thankyou(1313) #1 /home/customer/www/example.com/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(331): WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array) #2 /home/customer/www/example.com/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(474): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #3 /home/customer/www/example.com/public_html/wp-content/themes/kalium-child/woocommerce/checkout/thankyou.php(26): do_action('woocommerce_bef...', 1313) #4 /home/customer/www/example.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-core-functions.php(345): include('/home/customer/...') #5 /home/customer/www/example.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/shortcodes/class-wc-shortcode-checkout.php(256): wc_get_template('checkout/thanky...', Array) #6 /home/customer/w in /home/customer/www/example.com/public_html/wp-content/themes/kalium-child/functions.php on line 208
There has been a critical error on this website.*

I'm sure there's something obvious that I'm missing here but I just can't work it out. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is returning null because it isn't finding anything in `$_product`.

You have `$product` grabbing the product in the loop without the underscore. Remove the underscore and it should be good.

`$thumbnail = $product->get_image();`

Comment: Knew it was something silly, thank you very much!